# MvxException: Failed to initialize ViewModel for type x from locator

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Calling on Xamarin and MvvmCross experts. I have been trying to debug this error for hours `MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type TestApp.Core.ViewModels.IngredientsViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator`. I have found the piece of code which actually causes this error, and it has to do with data extraction from a database using EFCore sqlite.

This is my first time using it ever for a mobile app so maybe you may spot something I can't. Below is all the information I deem adequate, please let me know if more is required! I hope the solution helps others.
**Please note when I comment out `GetIngredients` I do not get the error above.**

#### My App file in Core/Shared project

```
public class AppCore : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<TestContext>();
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<IIngredientRepository, IngredientRepository>();
        RegisterAppStart<IngredientsViewModel>();
    }
}
```

#### My DbContext

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext() : base()
    {
    }
    private const string _databaseName = "Test.db";
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string databasePath;
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();
                databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library", _databaseName); ;
                break;
            case Device.Android:
                databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), _databaseName);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Platform not supported");
        }
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={databasePath}");
    }
}
```

#### Repositories

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly TestContext Context;
    public Repository(TestContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList(); //after this line error is thrown
    }
}

public interface IIngredientRepository : IRepository<Ingredient> {}
public class IngredientRepository : Repository<Ingredient>, IIngredientRepository
{
    public IngredientRepository(TestContext testContext) : base(testContext)
    { }
}
```

#### My ViewModel

```
public class IngredientsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IIngredientRepository IngredientRepository { get; set; }

    public IngredientsViewModel(IIngredientRepository ingredientRepository)
    {
        IngredientRepository = ingredientRepository;
        GetIngredients(); //when commented out, the view loads fine
    }

    private void GetIngredients()
    {
        var ingredients = IngredientRepository.GetAll();
        Ingredients = new MvxObservableCollection<Ingredient>(ingredients);
    }

    private MvxObservableCollection<Ingredient> _ingredients;
    public MvxObservableCollection<Ingredient> Ingredients
    {
        get => _ingredients;
        set { SetProperty(ref _ingredients, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: There should be an internal exception that has a more detailed error message that is embedded in that MvxException. Can you post that?

My guess is that your Ingredient table hasn't been created and thats why you are encountering an error when querying all items in that table.

Comment: @pnavk do you mean information in the output window after the error is thrown? I saw a lot of .db file's not found. I think that points to the answer below. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TestContext.cs, try to add the following line in the constructor:

```
Database.EnsureCreated(); //returns boolean which could be used for some check if needed
```

And also, my suggestion would be to override OnModelCreating like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //creating tables according to UML
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>();

        //add one for each table
}
```

If this does not help, please try to check InnerException or to debug step by step.

Comment: fantastic! my view loads up without a problem now! I've realised in Android Device Monitor that my emulated device has an empty data file even after putting `Database.EnsureCreated()` and `Database.Migrate()` would you happen to know why?